# Libreoffice soffice always trigger document recovery dialog box though no file to be recovered

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I am using Libreoffice 5.2.7.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

When I do `soffice --show filename.odp` it always trigger document recovery dialog box even though there is no file to be recovered.

[image: document recovery dialog box]

After hitting ok, it will prompt me to select filename.odp to load which defeat the purpose of using `soffice --show`.

I had edited `registrymodifications.xcu` on recovery entries.  Removed /usr/bin/soffice and reinstall libreoffice.

Still the document recovery dialog box persist with soffice.  Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You say you're using 5.2.7.2, but your screen shot above shows 5.3.  What's with this?  Do you have both installed?  And if so which soffice are you running?  Also did this once work and then stop, or has it never worked?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the [LibreOffice User Profile](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile)?

To test `--show`, create `filename.odp` as a new presentation and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: restart in safe mode and reset to factory setting.  Above dialog still persist.